# How to type braces on Danish Mac keyboard when RDP'ing into Windows ?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

Context: I am on a Mac (Macbook Pro) running OS X Lion with a Danish keyboard layout. I sometimes have to RDP (using the Microsoft RDP client for Mac) into a Windows machine, that also has Danish keyboard layout.

In this environment I cannot figure out how to type curly brace `{}` or hard braces `[]`. On the windows machine I will use the AltGr key (right alt key, which is found on Danish Windows keyboard) + the `7` or `0` key for curly braces. But this does not work on Mac. There is no designated AltGr key, and trying the right Alt key does not work (I type nothing when trying the combination).

How do I type the characters in this environment, that would normally require the `AltGr` key ? Is there anyway to change the mapping so the right Alt key gets this function when I am connected to the Windows machine ?

Comment: Does for example control+option+7 or enter+7 (where enter is ⌅ / fn-return) work? You could also try using [KeyTweak](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060914024254779) on Windows.

Comment: Control+Option+7 actually works - don't know why I did not try that :-) You should put your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control + option functions as AltGr in some remote desktop or VM applications, apparently including Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection client.

In some other applications enter (⌅, not return) can be used for AltGr.

Another option might be to install Boot Camp drivers on Windows. It adds Apple versions of some keyboard layouts (that don't use AltGr) to the control panel. See [VMware KB: Using an alternate keyboard layout for a virtual machine in VMware Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005578).

Answer (score 1):

Here following works:
ctrl+option 7
cttrl+option 8

Actually using this in Affinity to adjust pencil seize.

Answer (score -1):

this my not be the right answer but it works in a pinch pull up the windows 7 onscreen keyboard. If you cant find it simply type on screen keyboard in you windows search bar. and use the alt gr key there. It does not fix you keyboard but it gets the job done